# If a = bc, and a and b are positive integers, for what cases is c also an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a = bc$, and $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, for what cases is $c$ also an integer?

Trying to show that if $c$ is an integer then $b$ divides $a$.

Comment: Um...  $c$ is an integer if and only if $b|a$.  That's the definition of $b|a$.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of "divides"? Is there anything to show?

Comment: if $a$ is less than $b$, then $c$ is less than $1$, if $a = b$, then $c = 1$, if $a $ is a multiple of $b$, then $c$ is an integer

Comment: What is your algebraic structure?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to math stack exchange! Your question is a little unclear to me, so feel free to comment on my answer or edit your question if this isn't the answer you are looking for.

To address your first question: maybe study the cases $a < b$ and $a \geq b$. You could prove that if $a < b$ and $a = bc$ for positive integers $a,b$ then $c$ is not an integer. For intuition, consider $4 = 8 \cdot (1/2)$. On the other hand, if $a \geq b$ and $a = bc$ for positive integers $a,b$ then $c$ must be an integer. For this, you would need to use a property of the positive whole numbers called "closure".

The second thing you mention seems different your first question. As others have mentioned, $c$ being an integer is the precise definition of what it means for $b$ to divide $a$, so you don't need to "show" that $c$ being an integer implies $b$ divides $a$, you can simply assert that $c$ is an integer **if and only if** $b$ divides $a$, by definition!